# Hibernate @BatchSize doesn't work as expected after session.flush

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using Hibernate 4.2, and i have a parent entity which contains a collections of child entities (One-To-Many ,fetch type is LAZY and annotated with `@BatchSize(size=100))`.

If i query and load few parent entities and call access that collection which contains child object, hibernate uses the `@BatchSize` as the expected.
But if i call session, flush and then do the same thing, it initializes collection only for that particular parent entity.

Is it the Hibernate expected behavior?

Edit: sample

```
    List parents = criteria.list()
    parents.get(0).getXs().get(0) // triggers loading Xs of all parents
```

vs

```
    List parents = criteria.list()
    session.flush()
    parents.get(0).getXs().get(0) // triggers loading Xs of only the first parent
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with `Session.flush`. Do you mean `Session.clear`?

Comment: No, i am sure that i use session flush, i have tested this. i know that if i didn't call session.flush, then my problem will be solved. but i want to know the theory behind this.

Comment: Could you try to use HQL to load parents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am going to answer my own question because i think this would help others.
I think this is the Hibernate behavior even though it is not mentioned in any document.
when we call Session.flush , it calls to the Flushing event listener and and i found this code in AbstractFlushingEventListenrner class

```
// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Post-flushing section
// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

/**
 * 1. Recreate the collection key -> collection map
 * 2. rebuild the collection entries
 * 3. call Interceptor.postFlush()
 */
protected void postFlush(SessionImplementor session) throws HibernateException {

    LOG.trace( "Post flush" );

    final PersistenceContext persistenceContext = session.getPersistenceContext();
    persistenceContext.getCollectionsByKey().clear();

    // the database has changed now, so the subselect results need to be invalidated
    // the batch fetching queues should also be cleared - especially the collection batch fetching one
    persistenceContext.getBatchFetchQueue().clear();
```

So this last line clears the BatchFetchQueue for the current context

Comment: I spent 2 days on that one. Except that my flush was called implicitly by my ejb boundary. Thanks for the research,

Answer (score 1):

So if I get your question correctly you do the following (pseudo code)

```
a = loadSomeEntity
b = loadSomeEntity
a.getXs.get(0) // triggers loading of Xs for a and b
```

vs

```
b = loadSomeEntity
session.flush
a = loadSomeEntity
a.getXs.get(0) // triggers loading only of Xs for a
```

This is strange to me, but if you do a session.commit or session.clear instead of the flush, it would be expected, because now b is no longer part of the session and therefor it is no candidate for batch fetching.

Comment: yes , but more accurately i use criteria.list , that means loading a and b is in a single line, then if i do a session.flush then batchsize doesn't work.